# Reload Dynamically Created Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application in which I'm dynamically creating controller classes in the `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.controller_reference` method when they don't exist w/ the help of `Object.const_set` and `Class.new`.

This works fine until I modify the controller that this dynamically created controller is based off of (this happens a **LOT** in development as I'm constantly making changes to the controller).

This throws the following Exception:

```
ArgumentError

A copy of Base::FooController has been removed from the module tree but is still active!
```

I have a `Base::FooController` that is the parent and I'm creating a controller on the fly called `Bar::FooController`.

This exception is being thrown in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_missing_constant`. Is there a way to reload/recreate this class and avoid the exception?

**activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb**

```
def load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
  log_call from_mod, const_name

   # I want to do a check here and recreate the controllers that are needed....

   unless qualified_const_defined?(from_mod.name) && Inflector.constantize(from_mod.name).equal?(from_mod)
     raise ArgumentError, "A copy of #{from_mod} has been removed from the module tree but is still active!"
   end

   ...
```

Comment: Do you know what changes that the modification is making? if so can you make it at creation time.

Comment: Well I'm constantly updating the controller while developing the application so I just need it to be reloaded instead of throwing that exception.

Comment: you are waaaayyyy off the beaten path here. Rails auto-loading will not work for you --- you're going to need to stop and start the development rails server with each change to your dynamically generated controller.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I realize that this is uncharted territory. Any ideas on how to reload these classes without stopping the server?

Comment: check out `Object.send(:remove_const, :FooController) if defined? FooController`

Comment: `Object.send(:remove_const, const_name) if defined? const_name`  gives me `constant Object::ApplicationController not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Try this property found in `config/environments/development.rb` & `config/environments/production.rb`:

> config.cache_classes = true

`config.cache_classes` controls whether or not application classes and modules should be reloaded on each request.

Also, look at the order of initialzing in #5 below(note the comment in blue).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: I currently has this value set to `false` because I don't want to cache the classes. I need them to be reloaded/recreated in each request.